# Sql Decimal(x,0) - Datatype advantange over Integer/Bigint

Tags: sql, integer, decimal, long-integer, biginteger

I just saw an sql configuration, that uses Decimal-datatypes
as ID Columns, instead of Ingeger/BigInt columns.

For example, it uses Decimal(9,0) or Decimal(38,0).
Why would you do that?
What's the advantage of using the Decimal Type as
Integer representation?
I see that there is an advantage, when you're values
needs to be bigger then BigInt. But why would you use Decimal(9,0)?

Comment: Because you can increase the precision  later but the datatype keeps the same. For example, in C# it maps to `decimal`, no matter the precision.

Comment: Another reason (that might be specific to SQL Server) is to be able to do floating point division without explicit casting. See this for an example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96653/1